# Understanding Barcodes of Variant Products

Tags: barcode

This is an exceptionally general question that likely has a yes/no answer.

Let's say we have a line of shoes in our retail store.

Size 5 and Size 6 both have different assigned barcodes, as I've learned is the standard.
Great, we can now track them as different products.

Barcodes have a manufacturer identifier on the left, and a product identifier on the right.

**My question:** if we look at the barcodes for the Size 5 and Size 6 of our shoes, can we ever know that they are both from the same line of product? Just from the barcode?

As far as I can see, there is no such information within barcodes. The two products are simply variants, yet their barcodes make them appear completely different. One could be a shoe, and one could be a pack of birthday balloons.

Or, can we tell, from a barcode, that two products are actually variants (in this cases, sizes) of the *same* product?

We could, of course, do a barcode lookup with an API, but there does not seem to be, in any of the JSON data I've looked at, any way to associate them with each other. Looking at MPN numbers, also, this does not seem to be a thing.
Titles can be similar, but they are rarely exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I work with barcodes of different kinds.

The question you have does in principle have a yes/no answer, if you think of regular "retail" barcodes such as EAN13 or UPC. These correctly as you say have 4 parts: `[country][company][item][checkdigit]`.  In this way, each product is unique by itself, and unrelated to other products.

But not all barcodes are like this. Other barcodes may contain data identifiers in a structured way. The most common is the [GS1 identifiers](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers). Different barcodes ("symbologies") can carry this structure, common variants are EAN128, Datamatrix/GS1 and QR/GS1, but others may be used as well. Using this logic, you can create a relation between your products, using things like LOT code or internal company numbers.

Finally, nothing prevents you from creating your own barcoding strategy using a separate code on the product/box. It could be a code128 with a structure you build yourself, such as product family, type, ...